# PYTHON | Apps Unable to Take Automated Mouse Input

Tags: python, mouse, pyautogui, pynput

Recently after upgrading to **Windows 11**, I've found that some apps can't receive automated mouse and keyboard actions. The script simply goes to a location and clicks but after going to the location, the program doesn't respond to the clicks. Further more, the mouse cursor doesn't change to indicated that the element is [clickable](https://previews.123rf.com/images/terrry4/terrry41905/terrry4190501002/122755848-computer-mouse-click-cursor-gray-arrow-icons-set-and-loading-icons-cursor-icon-vector-illustration.jpg). I've tried several methods already, PyDirectInput, Pynput and Pyautogui.

I'm running the script to the application Roblox and I'm using Pycharm as an IDE.

Script with pydirectinput:

```py
import pydirectinput
import pyautogui
import time

x, y = pyautogui.size()

def click_ratio(xr, yr):
    global x, y
    pydirectinput.click(int(x/xr), int(y/yr))

pyautogui.alert()
time.sleep(1)
click_ratio(1.057414291615035, 1.6881594372801876)
```

Script with pynput:

```py
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
import pyautogui
import time

x, y = pyautogui.size()
mouse = Controller()

def click_ratio(xr, yr):
    global x, y
    mouse.position((int(x/xr), int(y/yr)))
    mouse.click(Button.left, 2)

pyautogui.alert()
time.sleep(1)
click_ratio(1.057414291615035, 1.6881594372801876)
```

Script using pyautogui:

```py
import pyautogui
import time

x, y = pyautogui.size()

def click_ratio(xr, yr):
    global x, y
    pyautogui.click((int(x/xr), int(y/yr)))
    

pyautogui.alert()
time.sleep(1)
click_ratio(1.057414291615035, 1.6881594372801876)
```

The clicking works fine on Chrome. If anyone could help me, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the program you'd like to run is opened by admin.
Try to run your script by admin as well and see if it would solve your problem.

Comment: What makes you think that? Please read [answer]. We don't deal in wild guesses here.

Comment: Because I had same issue and had been solved by this way.

Comment: Forgot to update, I tried this and it didn't work when you first suggested it